# Change font size for all inline equations R markdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am creating a r-markdown file and using knitr to convert to HTML. When I inline an equation such as `X_1,...,X_n \sim N(0,1)` it gets converted to HTML output as this

[image: this].

The math text is oversized relative to the plain text font. I can correct this for a single equation with `\small X_1,...,X_n \sim N(0,1)`. However, I would prefer not to type `\small` hundreds of times throughout a document. Does anyone know how to correct this with a single settings change or modification so it's applied to all math text in the document?

Comment: You could add this to your css: `.math {font-size: small;}`

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the css settings, I tried this: 
---
title: "Title"
output: 
  html_document:
    css: .math {font-size: small;}
---

which resulted in an error "Error in yaml::yaml.load(string, ...) : 
  Scanner error: mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 4, column 26
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load_utf8 -> <Anonymous> -> .Call
Execution halted"

Comment: add this after your yaml <style>
.math {
  font-size: small;
}
</style>

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding the following CSS after your YAML, or include it in an external CCS document. Pandoc automatically wraps inline math in `<span>` tags with class `math`. By modifying the `math` class, we can adjust the font size.

```
<style>
.math {
  font-size: small;
}
</style>
```

Comment: To complement Peter's answer, RMarkdown also supports "other" languages. You can add the style definition is a *css code-chunk*, for this use the `{css}` instead of the "standard `{r} ` tag after the starting 3 backticks..