# R Markdown: Set math font size for an entire notebook output

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I'm creating a RMarkdown file and produce an notebook output. Within my file I use a lot of math equations. The default size of the equations is normal and that's oversized in relation to the other text. Before I include the tag `\small` hundred of times in each euqation I want to set the math size for the entire document.

Searching for solutions lead me to some threads, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47872597/change-font-size-for-all-inline-equations-r-markdown/67145793#67145793) one. But all my attempts failed to get this work.

It would be very nice if you can tell me what I've to do to set the math size for the entire document.

Best and thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@stschn the solution of the other post is applicable to Rmd's html_document and/or html_notebook output.

If you want to keep the css code within your document, Rmd allows you to specify a *css code chunk*.
Place the following at the top of your Rmd. Instead of  ```` ```{r ...} ```` use  ```` ```{css} ```` to tell RMarkdown to interpret the chunk as css.
For demo purposes, I set the font-size to x-large, you can use other standard sizes, e.g. small, large, x-small, etc. or define size in terms of measures like 8px.

```
# remember to use css as engine in the {} of this chunk
.math {
  font-size: x-large;
}
```

Then write something like this to see it work:

```
This allows me to set the size of math in inline equations, e.g. $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$.
That is awesome.
Does this also apply to regular equation?
$$\frac{sin(a)}{sqrt(D^2)}$$
```

This will produce the following output, if you render (knit) it to html_document or html_notebook output.

P.S. The 2nd formula is obvious for demo purposes :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! You place the css-chunk on top of the file. With regard to the linked thread, what does it mean to place this piece of chunk .math {...} after YAML?

Comment: you can embed css in different ways into a RMarkdown document:     
(i) external css; you link to this in the YAML     
(ii) you embed the css in the YAML       
(iii) - the option I described - you place a code-chunk for {css} under your YAML.

In the end, all variants are valid. I prefer the 3rd option, as in my opinion the YAML is kept for the document meta data, and the css if not linked from an external file sits in a code-chunk. Just be careful that this is a css chunk, i.e. you have to tell RMarkdown that this is css by `{css}` and not {r}.

It is up to you which variant to pick.

Comment: re the linked post, you do not have to use the html <style> tag.