# Change font size for all inline equations in R Markdown not working in HTML

Tags: r, r-markdown

In R Markdown, the default HTML font size for inline equations is too large for my taste (it seems more consistent with the body font in PDF and Word output). [Another extremely similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47872597/change-font-size-for-all-inline-equations-r-markdown) details two possible solutions: one applied at the individual formula level and the second to set the formula font size for the document. *I seek to set the formula font size for the entire document*. Thus far, I am unable to get the proposed solution to work and am seeking insight into how to get it to function properly.

## Formula Level Solution (Working)

> This is text, and here is an inline formula $W$

Results in [image]

When knitting HTML, this can be successfully changed for an individual formula as:

> This is text, and here is an inline formula $\small W$

Doing so results in [image]

## Document Level Solution (Not Working)

The previously cited [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47872597/change-font-size-for-all-inline-equations-r-markdown) indicates that one should be able to add inline custom css. The R Markdown Cookbook makes [similar suggestions](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-css.html#html-css) regarding inline css.

For me, the proposed solution is not working. I've tried the following variations:

**First**

````
```{=css}
<style>
.math {
  font-size: tiny;
}
</style>
```
````

**Second**

````
```{css}
<style>
.math {
  font-size: tiny;
}
</style>
```
````

**Third, outside a code chunk**

```
<style>
.math {
  font-size: tiny;
}
</style>
```

**Fourth, outside a code chunk**

```
<style type="text/css">
  .math {
  font-size: small;
}

  body{
  font-size: 12pt;
}
</style>
```

This successfully changes the body text to make it larger, but does not set the equation font smaller. Solution Four is a workaround, but I'd much prefer to change the formula font smaller than make the body font larger. However, it does indicate that the `<style>` tag will work outside of a code chunk.

None of these approaches seem to change the size of the formula fonts. Several of them can be used to change the body font, either inside or outside a code chunk. I've also referenced an external style.css document, but that doesn't work for formula fonts either. I think I'm going about this the wrong way. *Any guidance regarding what I am overlooking would be most appreciated*.